# Como 'Manipular' Carrinho Fora do Sistema Magento - API

Tags: magento

Olá,
Bom, eu gostaria de integrar o sistema Magento no meu site(apenas 1 página), pois tem um módulo de integração rápida do sistema checkout do MOIP, assim eu não precisaria fazer na mão todo o sistema, já que existe um modulo pronto para esta plataforma(Magento).

Então essa foi a única saída que eu percebi para ter um checkout transparente da MOIP de forma rápida. Visando isso, eu quero saber como adicionar itens no carrinho do Magento(através do PHP por exemplo), para que quando eu redirecionar o cliente para página de checkout(ai que entra o sistema Magento com modulo do MOIP) possa aparecer os itens do carrinho direitinho, como se a pessoa tivesse desde o inicio adicionando os itens no carrinho através da plataforma Magento.

Isso é possivel? Como faço? Outra alternativa?

Parece até uma gambiarra, instalar uma plataforma numa pasta apenas para ter um modulo do MOIP, mas essa é a unica alternativa(mais rápida, acredito eu) que tive para passar por este problema..

Qualquer esclarecimento, só pedir.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se o que eu disser vai lhe ajudar, porque não é uma reposta definitiva mas já passei por problema semelhante porém no meu caso eu realmente precisava *"emular"* uma compra fora do Magento, mas fingindo que a pessoa tivesse feito todo o processo dentro dele e digo que consegui chegar perto, porem desisti o Magento é cheio de frescura e nuances o que torna a coisa BEM complicada. Então sinceramente acho que o tempo e bateção de cabeça que vai ter tentando fazer isso será melhor usar o SDK do MOIP que dá mais jogo. Mas vou dizer mais ou menos até onde cheguei.

**1) Programação com os Objetos**
O primeiro modo que encontrei para se fazer isso é usando as classes, funções e objetos do próprio Magento, você inclue o arquivo "Mage.php" em um arquivo PHP qualquer e começa a montar o carrinho chamando as funções, sim o Magento literalmente monta o carrinho aos poucos, ele cria uma sessão para aquela compra, depois adiciona o usuário a que pertence a compra, depois adiciona os produtos para aquela sessão e usuário, depois adiciona mais frete e pagamento e por fim gera uma ordem, tudo isso dentro das tabelas e dentro dessa ordem ou seja você não consegue calcular frete sem usuário cadastrado por exemplo, ou seja só com um CEP avulso por exemplo.

Algo mais ou menos assim *(isso é so mais ou menos a sintax para rodar precisa de mais coisas):*

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php"); 
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session"); 

$cart = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/cart"); 
$cart->init();

$cart->addProduct(12, 3);
$cart->save();

var_dump($cart);
?>
```

Porém muda bastante de versão para versão de Magento e o que pretende fazer, então você terá que se aprofundar nós códigos da versão que esta usando e no que quer fazer, existe vários exemplos na internet não sei qual poderia ser últiu para você, vou jogar alguns para você ver.

[Exemplo 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838558/how-to-programmatically-add-a-product-with-custom-options-to-cart-in-magento) - 
[Exemplo 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804695/unable-to-add-product-to-cart-programmatically-in-magento) - 
[Exemplo 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553636/programmatically-add-product-in-cart-empty-cart) -
[Exemplo 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867045/magento-1-8-add-product-to-cart-using-php)

**2) Usando API do Magento**
Bem o que muita gente não sabe é que o Magento possui 2 sistema de API's uma REST que serve para fazer pequenas requisições internas e outra usando SOAP (v1 e v2) que você consegue fazer quase todas as operações dentro do Magento *(mesmo que mega lentas pois como são lentas se louco)*. Para se usar a API você primeiramente deve entrar nas configurações lá na área de 'admin' e na aba API criar um usuário e senha e definir as permições desse usuário, seria algo tipo uma chave. Vale lembrar que existe discrepancias entre a versão v1 da API e a versão v2, então tera que testar as duas pra ver qual irá funcionar no seu proprosito, no meu caso usei as duas para cada situação que precisei um 'modulo' que só funciono bem em uma versão.

A partir disso basta acessa a API com um arquivo PHP qualquer mesmo que rodando em sua máquina local, algo mais ou menos assim.

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient("http://seuhost.com.br/api/v2_soap/?wsdl");
$sessionId = $proxy->login("user-Criado", "senha-Criada");     
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId, "3");
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Bem para usar essas API terá que estudar o código, pois ele é fragmentafdo em várias mini chamadas como frete, pagamento, usuários, cupom entre outras coisas vou apontar os links que eu acho que você precisa.
[Introdução a API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html) -
[Criação de Carrinho com Usuário](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.html) -
[Criar Ordem com o Carrinho](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.order.html)

Nos dois casos um problema que talvez eu veja é como você vai atrelar o usuário ao carrinho, em geral o Magento precisa saber antes quem é para montar o carrinho, você pode até usar um usuário 'guest' porém ao chegar no chekout isso da muito problemas de pagamento e frete dentro do Magento, então não saberia dizer como você poderia fazer isso, no meu caso eu recebia os dados antes de tudo e procurava dentro do Magento (no DB) o email da pessoa caso eu achasse eu pegava o ID do usuário e embutia dentro do carrinho, caso eu não econtrasse eu criava um usuário, e depois montava o carrinho, ordem e etc.

*Sei que links não são recomendados mas os códigos de exemplos são bem grandes e complexos, desculpe.*

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @SK15, mas como disse no tópico, esperava que fosse mais simples e a idéia era que fosse mais rápido, mas como o conteúdo era escasso para eu começar a engatinhar e realizar o processo, eu decidi usar a API do Moip para fazer no site mesmo, obrigado pelo tópico, talvez eu voltei aqui futuramente caso eu queira embarcar nessa aventura! Abraços!